# Conditionally instantiate a different class

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

Assume that I've the following classes:

1) Animal class, a base class

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void Hello();
}
```

2) Dog class, extends from Animal class

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void Hello() {
        System.out.println("I'm Dog");
    }
}
```

3) Wolf class, extends from Animal class

```
public class Wolf extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void Hello() {
        System.out.println("I'm Wolf");
    }
}
```

In the Dog class's constructor or newInstance method, is there a way to switch/turn itself into a Wolf class under a certain condition, say during full moon?  So, basically, if the caller does something like below, the variable "a" will be a Wolf object during full moon, instead of a Dog object.

```
Animal a = (Animal) Class.forName("Dog").newInstance();
```

Comment: The neat way to do this is to have another entity be responsible for the instantiation. The check for a full moon would go there. You shouldn't want to turn an object into another object in its own constructor.

Comment: I don't have controlled over that.  In the above scenario, the caller is actually a vendor software that we used.  Animal class is a vendor class.  Dog & Wolf are two classes that we created.  Vendor gives us a place to register a callback class, in this case, Dog would be the callback class that we registered.  But under some condition, I want it to be the Wolf class.

Comment: Well, if the thing you register is the class itself and not some `Supplier`, you are out of luck. A `Dog` constructor always returns an instance of `Dog` or throws an Exception, there are no other options.

Comment: @Hulk  Thank you.  I guess I'm out of luck, cause our Vendor only provide a way to register a class name and the class must  extends from their base class.

Comment: You could also consider using composition instead of inheritance - your `MyAnimal` constructor could initialize a member, lets call it  `IBehavior behavior` with a `DogBehavior` or a `WolfBehavior`, depending on the phase of the moon.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a wrapper for `Animal` to delegate to the actual `Animal` you wish to track and; then include in the delegator wrapper a method to swap delegates based on the class name of the `Animal` you want. Here is an example class:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    public abstract String hello();

    static class Dog extends Animal {

        @Override
        public String hello() {
            return "I'm Dog";
        }
    }

    static class Wolf extends Animal {

        @Override
        public String hello() {
            return "I'm Wolf";
        }
    }

    static class AnimalWrapper extends Animal {

        private Animal delegate = new Dog();

        public void delegateTo(String className) throws Exception {
            this.delegate = (Animal) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public String hello() {
            return delegate.hello();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnimalWrapper animal = new AnimalWrapper();
        System.out.println("Animal says: " + animal.hello());
        animal.delegateTo(Wolf.class.getName());
        System.out.println("Animal says: " + animal.hello());
        animal.delegateTo(Dog.class.getName());
        System.out.println("Animal says: " + animal.hello());
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56138936)

Comment: this might be the only option I've.

Comment: This is a very clean, and common approach, for the scenario you have. There are other (well proven) similar patterns out there, in case your scenario deviates somehow. Here is a great overview of most of these: https://www.baeldung.com/java-structural-design-patterns

Comment: @Robert I Just edited the code to use `class.getName()` instead of literal String. That's a demo draft and you can clean up more the code, including receiving just the `class` object rather than its name or even a `Supplier<Animal>`, so you can use arguments such as `Dog::new` and `Wolf::new`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. 
It looks like you need something like factory (search for factory design pattern) that will be responsible for creating instance of class you need.